# Google Photos REST API “BASE_URL=dv” return "302 Moved" error

Tags: base-url, google-photos, google-photos-api

I was using Google Photos REST API to download my videos. Based on the documentations, I was using the below curl command with `BASE_URL=dv` parameters to get the video file and getting **302 Moved** error but video is in `READY` state. Pasted the output below.
Kindly help to resolve the error.

**API:**

```
curl --compressed --output - --request GET   --header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'   --header 'Accept: application/json' 'BASE_URL=dv'
```

**Output:**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="VIDEO_URL">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to download the video as a file using curl command.

In this case, please use the following curl command.

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl -L "base-url=dv" -o sampleFilename
```

- In this case, it seems that the access token is not required to be used.
- Please use `-L` and `--location` for the redirect.
- When `base-url` is `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/###`, please use `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/###=dv` as the URL as follows.

  ```
    curl -L "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/###=dv" -o sampleFilename
  ```

#### References:

- [Video base URLs](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items#video-base-urls)
- [curl.1 the man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Than you very much. It is resolved the issue.
Also, I found ```curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L)``` for ```libcurl``` usage.